# Can I have an AnnotationProcessor defined in maven which will cause compilation errors in my IDE?

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, m2e, annotation-processing

Background: I'm adding some annotations to one of our test modules such that everything in a specific package needs to be annotated. I have already written an AnnotationProcessor which does this.

The problem: My processor successfully works for me when I run `mvn generate-test-sources` and `mvn test`. However, I would like it to show errors in our development IDEs (Eclipse and IntelliJ). I have not tried with IntelliJ, but with Eclipse, I'm having issues. I've installed  m2e-apt, but when I toggled between the settings it didn't seem to work. A test which was not properly annotated was not getting errors (and other modules which didn't inherit the processor plugin got NPEs when being built).

What are my options for having streamlined capability to show errors in IDEs for AnnotationProcessors?

Comment: apt is obsolete. Don't use anything related to it. Does Eclipse something like Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing option to specify the annotation processors?

Comment: I see no Annotation option under Java->Compiler.